# Did Bran see Arya when he breaks eye contact with the Night King?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In my mind, that final moment in *Game of Thrones* S08E03 between Bran and the Night King was an indication of what was to come.

It took me a while to understand why the Night King tilts his head after Bran breaks eye contact with him. I think Bran knows Theon must charge the Night King in order to make Bran look unprotected. Bran brings him right in and since Arya can easily walk around dead people without being noticed, I think he sees her walk up and jump.

Anyone else have any thoughts? I just can't figure out why he tilts his head at Bran.

Comment: Like Niffer was attempting to answer, we don't know yet if we are really done with the NK or not and/or if there are going to be any more explanation for things pertaining to WW and the [secret] history of Westoros or if we're just going to have to hold our breath and hope the prequel TV series (if it gets picked up) will explain WW/NK/3ER semantics better to us. I for one hope the fantasy genre aspects aren't as subverted as much as this episode makes it appear they were and there is still some catch there, but R'hllor comes of easily as an a** too, so who knows! :p

Comment: Why is this important? if he saw her or not, it doesn't change the outcome (at least what was shown). I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @Luciano None of it's important, it's a TV show. But Game Of Thrones is one of those TV shows where sometimes a lot is said in a small gesture or expression

Comment: What I mean is: it doesn't make any difference. If he saw and the night king caught it, or if the night king didn't catch that, or if Bran didn't see her at all: she still jumped, the NK caught her and she killed him. I fail to see the importance of _that_ particular moment. Unlike when Bran stops Theon, for example, that has an actual significance to the story.

Comment: Maybe Bran was "far-seeing" ( forgot the actual word ) Arya. The NK was probably confused as to why Bran is zoning out when his death is standing in front of him. NK must be wondering what is so important at this point or maybe he expected Bran to have a dialogue with him.

Answer (score -1):

The head tilt had me confused and then I re-watched the episode. Second time, still confused. But then, third time I watched just that particular scene... and you know what I saw? Bran initially looked at the Night King, the Night King looked at Bran. Camera moves back a little so you can see the Night King's sword over his shoulder, you can see Bran looking at the Night King, then to the sword, then back to the Night King. THAT's when the head tilt happened. In some weird way it looked like Bran was telling him what to do, and the Night King seemed so surprised by it but followed "orders". If Bran turns out to be a villain so much is going to finally make sense!

And by the way, I don't think Bran saw Arya at all.